# Facebook like button for Java JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, facebook-like

I am developing a Java enterprise application and I am usign JSF, mostly Primefaces.
I need to put facebook like buttons. Do you know if there are any facebook like jsf components around? or something else?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need anything specific. It doesn't interact with your backend, so just use the fb javascript.